# Is there a way to push epubs to iBookstore moreover using iTunes Producer?

Tags: publishing

I am wondering if there is an API that will allow me to push epubs, with all the needed meta data, to Apple iTunes/iBookstore. Currently I am using the desktop app iTunes Producer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is most likely an API working between iTunes Producer and the iBookstore, **but AFAIK Apple has not published it**. It is of course much easier for Apple to control a protocol— and change if needed—when you control both client and server sides (client: iTunes Producer, server: iBookstore). This keeps development cheaper than with a published API and it might even allow Apple offload some of the work to the client side that they don't want to re-check on the server.

If you are not willing to do repetitive work using iTunes Producer, I see two possible alternatives:

- checkout if any of the iBookstore aggregators ([approved](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/displayAggregators?ccTypeId=13) or [others](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2436878?threadID=2436878&tstart=0&messageID=11553151)) has an API you can use. Of course a commercial service costs you, reducing earnings from the list price down from 70% when directly dealing with Apple¹.
- programmatically drive the iTunes Producer application to do the uploading  using the [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html)². This might actually be quicker to develop than trying to interface with an API programmatically.

¹ <sub>I am not sure if any aggregators have an API available. Earning will  e.g. be down to 63%  using [Lulu](http://connect.lulu.com/t5/ISBN-Distribution/How-to-get-your-eBook-on-the-iBookstore-Authors/ta-p/33460); to 60% using [Smashwords](http://www.smashwords.com/about/how_to_publish_ipad_ebooks)</sub>

² <sub>I have done that kind of automation, programming the 'driver'
for the `.tiff` to `.djvu` conversion in a Windows GUI application.</sub>

Comment: Anthon, thanks for your answer. My goal here is to link our CMS with iBookstore, but without reducing our % earnings.